# What are differences between "ins" and "in"?

Tags: preposition

My German teacher explained this last year and I never really understood when to use "ins" and when to use "in", I know they are both two way prepositions but what's the difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Welcome to GL&U!


"*Ins*" is a contraction of "*in das*". So, whenever you have a situation where you would say "*in das*", then you could use "*ins*" instead.

> *Wir gehen **in das** Haus.* = *Wir gehen **ins** Haus.*

Comment: I'd go further and say that _Wir gehen in das Kino_ sounds quite awkward and you **have to** use the contraction _Wir gehen ins Kino_.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: What sounds awkward to you? Nobody has to use "ins", just because it is possible. I don't understand why there are 7 upvotes on this misguiding hint. `Die Einsicht in das
 bürgerlich aufklärerische Element Homers ist von der spätromantisch-deutschen Interpretation der Antike, die Nietzsches frühen Schriften folgte, unterstrichen worden.` Theodor W. Adorno, Dialektik d. Aufklärung.

Comment: @HendrikVogt and user unknown: I was merely trying to answer the specific question, not overload John with too many explanations. Perhaps I could have chosen a better example that wouldn't lead into a whole different discussion. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I edited the answer to switch to "Haus" instead of "Kino"

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Just because noone actually says that it is not wrong to use the expanded form.

Comment: @user: "Die Einsicht in das bürgerlich aufklärerische Element" sounds good; in fact, it sounds better to me than the version with "ins". I can't say any rule here, but for frequently used phrases like "ins Haus" and "ins Kino" I'd _always_ use the contraction unless I want to specify _which_ house or cinema I go into. (For example, "Ich gehe in das Restaurant auf der anderen Straßenseite" sounds good to me.)

Comment: @H.B.: Even if it's not _wrong_ to say "ich gehe in das Bett" - I'd still say you _have to_ say "ich gehe ins Bett" because otherwise people won't easily understand you.

Comment: @Kevin: I find it quite OK that you didn't overload your answer. But I don't think "Haus" instead of "Kino" makes much of a difference.

Comment: "in das" für alltägliches klingt wirklich seltsam. Es betont einfach zu sehr. "Ich gehe in das Haus" klingt danach, als ob er in ein spezielles Haus geht, auf welches dann beim Reden vielleicht auch noch gezeigt wird. Wenn es aber nicht wichtig ist um welches Haus es sich handelt, bzw. eh klar ist um welches, dann würde ich bei "ins" bleiben.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Das war aber nun die Frage, wann es einen Unterschied macht. "Ich kann die Frage in das Gegenteil verkehren" klingt auch völlig normal, würde ich sagen. Dass es an der Häufigkeit der Benutzung liegt halte ich für Quatsch "Ich gehe ins Verließ" sage/schreibe ich heute erstmalig. "Ins Bett gehen" beschreibt einen generischen Vorgang wie "zu Bett gehen" - es ist kein spezifisches Bett von Interesse hier. "Wenn Du die Wahl hast, gehst Du in das Kino oder in das Theater?" ist aber m.E. auch völlig legitim. Für die w. u. m. Formen (in die Oper, in den Weinkeller) gibt es auch k. Abk.

Comment: @user: OK, es kann gut sein, dass die Häufigkeit der Benutzung keine Rolle spielt. Wie gesagt, ich kenne keine Regel. Aber wenn ich Dich richtig verstehe, schreibt Du ja auch selbst, dass es manchmal einen Unterschied macht, ob man "ins" oder "in das" verwendet" (siehe auch Ferocs Kommentar). Und ohne Kontext klingt weiterhin "ich gehe in das Kino" sehr merkwürdig in meinen Ohren.

Comment: Meine These ist, dass man aus keinem Satz, der `ins` benutzt, ohne Kontext rückschliessen kann, dass `in das` falsch gewesen wäre - zumindest nicht aus den bislang diskutierten. Dann kann man aber auch nicht sagen, dass es immer `ins` heißen muss. Im Falle des zu Bett/ins Bett Gehens kann man etwa fragen: `Nimmst Du den Schlafsack oder legst Du Dich in das Bett?` mit der Antwort `Ich gehe in das Bett`. Ähnlich lassen sich auch Kinobeispiele konstruieren. "Gehen wir in das kleine Kino, in das Kino mit Sitzheizung oder in das Theater neben dem Park?" - klingt das immer noch merkwürdig?

Comment: Dass eine Konstruktion merkwürdig klingt kann daran liegen, dass man vorab schon einen Kontext im Kopf hat.

Comment: @user: Ich glaube langsam, wir sind uns einig. Manchmal heißt es "ins", manchmal "in das", je nach Kontext, und manchmal ist es egal.

Comment: @Feroc: "ins" is always referring to a specific instance, if it really did not matter you would use "in ein" instead. It seems to me that the lacking use of "in das" in many cases just makes it sound awkward while it should really be equivalent *by definition*.

Comment: @H.B.: In spoken language, there's no such thing as _definition_ - it's all _use_ (mit Grüßen von allen Buchmachern und Buchhaltern `:-)`).

Comment: @HendrikVogt: There are enough words, for which there is a definition - spoken or written. Think about contracts, about ordering 3 Pizzas by telephone. "Drei" is defined, "Pizza" is defined. "3x 0,2l Apfelsaft". Immer rein in das Vergnügen! ;)

Comment: @user: OK, for "drei" I agree. But what is "Pizza"? It's some kind of food, yes, but there are lots of versions that I wouldn't call "Pizza" anymore. Recently I ordered "Apfelschorle" in an Italian restaurant, and it was neither cold nor sparkling, nor did it taste much of apple. It certainly didn't match _my_ definition of "Apfelschorle".

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Which means, that you have some definition of Apfelschorle in mind, which didn't match that one, of the restaurant, or the restaurant made something wrong. It doesn't mean that Apfelschorle is undefined.